# Iteration through array

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, iteration

I'm having trouble iterating through a for loop to get the index in an array. When the event handler is triggered it goes straight to the last index instead of going to the next index.

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("question-container"); // returns a nodeList
var questionArray = jQuery.makeArray(elems);

nextButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < questionArray.length; i++) {
        $(questionArray).hide();
        $(correct).hide();
        $(questionArray[i]).show();
    }
});
```

Html is 8 divs that are identical to this

```
<div class="question-container">

            <h2>How many rocketships do you see?</h2>
            <img class="small-img" src="img/rocket.png">
            <div>
                <button class="one" id="butt1" value="1">1</button>
                <button class="one" id="butt2" value="2">2</button>
                <button class="one" id="butt3" value="3">3</button>
                <button class="one" id="butt4" value="4">4</button>
                <button class="one" id="butt5" value="5">5</button>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: With jQuery, you don't actually need to use native `addEventListener` you may bind `click` event handler by simply doing [`$('.question-container').click(...`](https://api.jquery.com/click/), also hide/show has shorthand [`.toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-duration-complete)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have 8 questions but only one is visible at a time and when one press the *next* button (not shown in your code) the current question is hidden and the next one is shown.

If so, here is a proposition

```
/* CSS */

.question-container {
    display: none;
}

.question-container-visible {
    display: block;
}

/* JavaScript */

const questionArray = [...document.getElementsByClassName("question-container")]; // this is of type Array
let questionIndex = 0; // keep track of the question which must be shown

nextButton.addEventListener('click', evt => {
    questionIndex++; // show the next question
    showQuestion();
});

function showQuestion() {
    questionArray.forEach((question, index) => {
        // show only the question which has an index equal to questionIndex
        question.classList.toggle('question-container-visible', index === questionIndex);
    });
}

showQuestion(); // show the first question
```

If we assume that the first question has the class `question-container-visible` from the start the JS code could simplify to

```
const questionArray = [...document.getElementsByClassName("question-container")];
let questionIndex = 0;

nextButton.addEventListener('click', evt => {
    questionIndex++;
    questionArray.forEach((question, index) => {
        question.classList.toggle('question-container-visible', index === questionIndex);
    });
});
```